# multile resultset from stored procedure using fluent api

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ef-fluent-api

I am using stored procedure to retrieve data from database. This stored procedure multiple result set.
and we are using fluent api. In repository method I am calling stored procedure as follows

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetWithRawSql(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return  DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters).ToList();           
    }
```

Following is stored procedure. But I am not getting expected result.
Please can any one help.

```
Create PROCEDURE SelRefRecoFactor_RegStatus
@BizID bigint
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RecCnt INT
SELECT RegistrationStatusCode,BusinessDetail.UserId,  UserReferenceTierId,      CASE AllowReservationConfirmation WHEN 0 THEN 'No' WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS AllowReservationConfirmation
 FROM BusinessDetail WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN UserLogin WITH (NOLOCK) on BusinessDetail.UserId= UserLogin.UserId
WHERE BusinessId =@BizID

SELECT @RecCnt = COUNT(ReferenceTier1PercentValue) FROM ReferenceTierInfo  WITH (NOLOCK)  
INNER JOIN BusinessDetail WITH (NOLOCK) on BusinessDetail.UserId=ReferenceTierInfo.UserId WHERE BusinessDetail.BusinessId =@BizID  AND ( GETDATE() between FromDate and ToDate)

IF(@RecCnt>0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT ReferenceTier1PercentValue, ReferenceTier2PercentValue  FROM ReferenceTierInfo  WITH (NOLOCK)  
         INNER JOIN BusinessDetail WITH (NOLOCK) on BusinessDetail.UserId=ReferenceTierInfo.UserId WHERE BusinessDetail.BusinessId =@BizID   AND ( GETDATE() between FromDate and ToDate)
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ReferenceTier1PercentValue, ReferenceTier2PercentValue FROM ReferenceTierInfo WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE UserId = 0  AND ( GETDATE() between FromDate and ToDate)
    END

SELECT @RecCnt=  COUNT(RecommendationPercent) FROM RecommendationPercentInfo  WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN BusinessDetail  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON BusinessDetail.UserId = RecommendationPercentInfo.UserId 
INNER JOIN CountryMaster WITH (NOLOCK)  ON RecommendationPercentInfo.CurrencyCode = CountryMaster.CurrencyCode 

  WHERE BusinessId =@BizID AND (getdate() between FromDate and ToDate)
IF(@RecCnt>0)
    BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT   RecommendationPercentInfo.RecommendationPercent,
      RecommendationPercentInfo.RecommendationService
    FROM
      RecommendationPercentInfo WITH (NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN BusinessDetail WITH (NOLOCK) ON (BusinessDetail.UserId = RecommendationPercentInfo.UserId)
      INNER JOIN CountryMaster WITH (NOLOCK) ON (RecommendationPercentInfo.CurrencyCode = CountryMaster.CurrencyCode)
    WHERE
  BusinessId = @BizID AND 
  getdate() BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
         SELECT DISTINCT RecommendationPercent, RecommendationService FROM RecommendationPercentInfo  WITH (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN CountryMaster WITH (NOLOCK)  ON RecommendationPercentInfo.CurrencyCode = CountryMaster.CurrencyCode 
         INNER JOIN BusinessDetail  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON BusinessDetail.CountryCode = CountryMaster.CountryCode 
         WHERE BusinessId =@BizID AND (getdate() between FromDate and ToDate) AND RecommendationPercentInfo.UserId = 0 
    END
```

END

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Are you getting an Error Message, No Results or Incorrect Results?

Comment: Its not giving result. It is not getting any error,